# CSS quotes in title, and quote in a quote

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some trouble with quotation marks in my Wordpress site since I used a new theme and added a few plug-ins.

First problem : I'd like to have French quotation marks (« ») in the title of my pages (I'm talking about the HTML `<title>`), as it was before, for instance [here](http://www.revue-ballast.fr/herve-kempf/).

Second problem : I have blockquotes in my posts (with French quotes) which sometimes contain another quote : I'd like these "inside quotes" to have double quotation marks (" "). I tried to do this with the CSS quotes property but it doesn't seem to work. For instance [here](http://www.revue-ballast.fr/repolitiser-la-monnaie/) (4th blockquote).

Some more information : I use Qode Bridge theme, and a few plug-ins, especially Yoast SEO that can have an impact on the title issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should have profit of CSS **`quotes`** property. Have a look on this example:

```css
.guillemets {
  quotes: "«\00A0""\00A0»";
  font-style: italic;
}
.guillemets::before {
  content: open-quote;
}
.guillemets::after {
  content: close-quote;
}
.guillemets .guillemets {
  quotes: "\"" "\"";
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="guillemets">consectetur adipiscing</span> elit. Etiam et porttitor turpis. Aenean eget ligula tristique, aliquet quam sit amet, faucibus nunc. Ut quam dui, vulputate sit amet nunc id, aliquet commodo augue.
  <span class="guillemets">Nulla <span class="guillemets">efficitur</span> nisi dignissim erat mollis</span>, nec feugiat felis egestas.
</p>
```

The `\00A0` is the unbreakable space wich is needed after opening *guillemets* and before the closing one in french typography.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Could I replace .guillemets by the HTML tag blockquote ?

Comment: @mhr Yes, you can replace it by any valid CSS selector.

Comment: OK thanks, so I'm using your last bit of code to indicate a quote in a quote, thanks !

Any idea for the <title> tag ?

Comment: @mhr You should be able to enclose it in a `<span class="guillemets">...</span>` too. But I d'ont know how your Wordpress works and if it allows tags in title filed.

Comment: Well, actually, I'm thinking it may be the Yoast SEO plugin which rewrites title, and by doing this overwrites French quotes with " " ; but I can't find a way to avoid this...

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `« »` inside of an extra `<p>` or `<span>`. I would prefer `<span>` because it doesn't add an extra break.

The `""` can be also shown inside of the `<p>` or `<span>`. The better way is probably to put them inside of `''` small quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

for block quotes use `<blockquote>` tag of HTML.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_quotation_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should try using UTF symbols:

```
&#171;
&#xab;
&laquo;
```

Left angle quotes

```
&#187;
&#xbb;
&raquo;
```

Right angle quotes

Available here:
http://character-code.com/french-html-codes.php